# Branch Then 'Reset' Rails Git Repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a bit of a tricky problem. I restarted a current rails project from scratch in a new folder because I was redoing the app as a personal exercise. We've run into some issues on the 'official' version and now need to restart the project.

The problem is that we've been using git to keep track on the official project but I haven't been using it for my personal version.

I've branched the official git master repository using

```
git checkout -b restart_app
```

Now I'd like to clear out all the code in that branch and replace it with my personal version. I've tried to google the best approach to doing so but found some differing answers and I'm pretty new to working with git so I thought I'd put up a question here. What would be the best practice/solution for approaching this problem?

Comment: Cant you just delete all the existing project files, copy-paste in the new project files from the other folder and commit?

Comment: @Sharagoz, We need to keep the master branch as is for the moment because we're pretty far in otherwise I'd do just that.

Comment: I was talking about the `restart_app` branch

Comment: Ah okay, you can do that. I just thought it would be bad practice or something. Like I said, I'm pretty inexperienced so I wanted to be sure before I did anything irreversible

Comment: As long as you dont delete the `.git` folder there should be no problem. Git will remember the old files should you ever need them. I'd probably keep the old project on its own branch once `restart_app` becomes master, just for easy access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want replace all the files in restart_app with files from a different project folder"

Delete and replace the files by the ones you want.
The best practice is to do a `git rm *` first, then add your files, git add and commit.

A nice trick, you can use the `--work-tree` option of [`git`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git):

```
git checkout restart_app
git rm -rf .
git add -A .
git commit -m "empty restart_app"

git --work-tree=/path/to/untracked/code add .
git commit -m "add new code"
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I need to keep the master branch as it is for the time being. That's why I branched the project in the first place.

Comment: @SoSimple what do you need then? you want restart_app to be like master?

Comment: @SoSimple "I'd like to clear out all the code in that branch and replace it with my personal version.": which branch? and what "personal version"? is it some untracked code?

Comment: I want replace all the files in restart_app with files from a different project folder. Someone above suggested manually deleting everything from restart_app then copy/pasting from the other folder? Yes the second folder is completely untracked. I'm sorry, I thought I'd said that.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is pretty much exactly what I needed to know.